# unable to scrape table on website using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this table: https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added?page=1

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

root_url = "https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added"
html = requests.get(root_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

paging = soup.find("div",{"class":"row no-gutters tw-flex flex-column flex-lg-row tw-justify-end mt-2"}).find("ul",{"class":"pagination"}).find_all("a")
start_page = paging[1].text
last_page = paging[len(paging)-2].text

#
# outfile = open('gymlookup.csv','w', newline='')
# writer = csv.writer(outfile)
# writer.writerow(["Name", "Address", "Phone"])


pages = list(range(1,int(last_page)+1))
for page in pages:
    url = 'https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added?page=%s' %(page)
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    #print(soup.prettify())
    print ('Processing page: %s' %(page))

    coins = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"coingecko-table"})
    for element in coins:
        coin = element.find(class_='coin-name text-left tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted')
        price = element.find(class_='price text-right sorter-numeric tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted')
        print(coin,price)
        # hr = element.find('change1h').text
        # last_added = element.find('last_added').text

#         writer.writerow([coin, price, hr,last_added])
#
# outfile.close()
print('Done')
```

The print(coin,price) fails to print anything. Not sure why, any help welcome :)

Comment: Why not use the API (https://pypi.org/project/pycoingecko/)?

Comment: they don't have an endpoint for retrieving recently_added coins

Comment: I guess the data is added and its dynamic so `beautifulsoup` cant determine output

Comment: The data doesn't appear to be dynamic. I just want to take a snapshot of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `pandas` to get the table data.

Here's how:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added?page=1"
df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text, flavor="bs4")
df = pd.concat(df).drop(["Unnamed: 0", "Unnamed: 1"], axis=1)
df.to_csv("your_table.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is great, how would I solve for pagination?

Comment: Just loop thru the pages and keep adding dataframes to, say, a list and then concatenate all of them into one.

Comment: I don't know why, but for me it requires the html5lib installed

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which fetch data from one page for pagination you have already done so just another loop is required

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

root_url = "https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added?page=1"
html = requests.get(root_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

coin_lst=[]
price_lst=[]
coins = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"coingecko-table"})
for element in coins:
    coin=element.find_all("td",attrs={"class":"py-0 coin-name"})
    price=element.find_all("td",attrs={"class":"td-price price text-right"})
    for c in range(len(coin)):
        coin_lst.append(coin[c]["data-text"])
        price_lst.append(price[c].text.strip("\n"))
```

Output:

```
Coin_list
['Revolt',
 'StarShip',
 'Panda Finance',....]

Price_list
['$0.00003005',
 '$0.188834',
 '$0.00000071',...]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `Selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

url='https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added?page=1'
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
wd.get(url)
time.sleep(2) # sleep for a few seconds to allow loading the data

coin = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source)
for element in coin:
    coin = element.find(class_='coin-name text-left tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted')
    price = element.find(class_='price text-right sorter-numeric tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted')
    print(coin,price)
```

This will output:

```
<th aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Coin: No sort applied, activate to apply a descending sort" aria-sort="none" class="coin-name text-left tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-column="2" role="columnheader" scope="col" style="user-select: none;" tabindex="0" unselectable="on">
Coin
</th> <th aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Price: No sort applied, activate to apply a descending sort" aria-sort="none" class="price text-right sorter-numeric tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-column="3" role="columnheader" scope="col" style="user-select: none;" tabindex="0" unselectable="on">
Price
</th>
```